# Nested loop in Angular4 template without nesting elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3, angular2-template

I'd like to nest a loop in my angular template without nesting elements.

e.g. pseudocode:

`component.ts`

```
let titles: string[];
let content: { title: string, text: string }[];

getContentByTitle(t: string) {
  return this.content.filter(c => c.title === t);
}
```

`template.html`

```
<div myDirective *ngFor="let title of titles">
 {{title}}
 <div myDirective *ngFor="content of getContentByTitle(title)">
  {{content.text}}
  </div>
</div>
```

But this nests my divs. I'm trying to create a flat list, per:

```
<div myDirective>
{{title}}
</div>
<div myDirective>
{{content.text}}
</div>
<div myDirective>
{{content.text}}
</div>
<div myDirective>
{{title}}
</div>
<div myDirective>
{{content.text}}
</div>
etc...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this case you can use `ng-container`, you will write a nested code, but the output will not be nested.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let title of titles">
  <div myDirective>
   {{title}}
  </div>
  <ng-container *ngFor="text of getContentByTitle(title)">
    <div myDirective>
      {{text}}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

From the Angular [doc ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue):

The Angular `<ng-container>` is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

I hope it may help you!

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-container

```
<div myDirective>
  <ng-container *ngFor='let o of objects'>
     {{o}}
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

it unwrap as:

```
<div myDirective>
  {{o}}{{o}}{{o}}{{o}}...
</div>
```